# Чем открыть xlsx файл?

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте. Не могу разобраться с xls файлами. Чем можно их открыть? Работаю на QT Creator. Пытался добавить библиотеку qtxlsx - не получается. Проделал все, что написано на оф сайте. Не работает. QtCreator ее не видит. Пытался найти описание xls, xlsx формата, ничего толком не нашел. Может быть есть rfc какой-нибудь по этому поводу? Сам бы написал библиотеку для работы с xls файлами с радостью. Подскажите что делать пожалуйста?

Comment: xlsx - это зазипованный xml. Если есть желание написать свою библиотеку, то сперва unzip, потом парсинг xml.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Не могли бы Вы подсказать еще RFC по XLS пожалуйста?

Comment: Я не думаю, что разрабатывать такую библиотеку с нуля является хорошим делом. Слишком сложный форма. Ищите что-нибудь готовое по ключевому слову OpenXML. Для .NET есть хорошие библиотеки. Но я не в курсе либ для C++.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен. Попытался разобраться в xls формате. ничего у меня не получилось. В итоге подключил библиотеку libxl, но сказать, что она хорошо работает никак нельзя.